# Need help adding template for single page in Drupal 7

Tags: php, templates, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I need some help with this one.  I have looked all over here for an answer, found a similar question but the answer did not work for me.  I have set up a new page in drupal 7 titled "new-setup".  The node ID for this page is 3.  I have created a custom theme 'new-theme' which exists as a folder within sites/all/themes.  Everything is good up to this point...this is the default theme for new pages added.  However I need to set up a page template for my "new-setup" page. I have added a templates foder within my 'new-theme' and added a 'page-node-3.tpl.php' template as my 'new-setup' page has a node ID of '3'.  On other boards, this seems to be the proper route for setting up a template, but I have tried for several hours and cannot get it to work.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have-you trash your cache ?

Comment: Yep, cache has been cleared multiple times.  Any other recs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `page--node--3.tpl.php` file in your themes directory & clear cache.

Answer (score 1):

in a template.php on your theme directory put something like

```
XXXX_preprocess_page($vars) { 
    if (isset($vars['node']) && $vars['node']->id == 3 ) { 
        array_unshift($vars['theme_hook_suggestions'], "page__bar"); 

    }
}
```

this will use page--bar.tpl.php for node of id 3
XXXX should be replaced by your theme name

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I do this process, my page simply spits out your above code in text format.

Comment: Actually, I lied.  I am getting the following....'Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed'.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which template you are trying to override and your theme.
But generally this will work.
Override page.tpl.php with "page--node--3.tpl.php".
Override html.tpl.php with "html--node--3.tpl.php".
Override node.tpl.php with "node--3.tpl.php"

There are all outlined at: [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)

The posts you were reding may have been for Drupal 6 which did not need the double dash if I remember correctly.

You can create your own suggestions but I think the above will serve your purpose.